Package `Solana-program vX.X.X` cannot be built because it requires rustc X.X.X or newer
When I run anchor build I get the error:
error: package solana-program v1.18.26 cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.75.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.72.0-dev
Either upgrade to rustc 1.75.0 or newer, or use
cargo update -p solana-program@1.18.26 --precise ver
where ver is the latest version of solana-program supporting rustc 1.72.0-dev
How can I tell anchor to use a later version of solana?
when I run rustc --version it prints: 1.79.0

Anchor uses the rust compiler that ships with your Solana tools version. You probably want to install a more recent Solana version like:
solana-install init 1.18.17
Solana-install is deprecated so if you are on a version beyond 1.18.20 or so you will probably use
agave install update
instead
